# Cannot read history from useHistory() in HOC Component

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

In order to handle authentication / conditional routing in my App, I decided to bring in a HOC component that, based on a switch statement, checks whether a component should be rendered or not.

Of course I could get the same by defining the conditions in the components themselves, but now it allows me to have a single file to handle this.

However, using the `useHistory()` hook seems to return `history` as undefined. Likely since my app Routes are not written in a conventional way (`AllowAccess` is the HOC component here):

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/success' component={AllowAccess(SuccessComponent)}></Route>
    <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Are there ways so I can acces the history prop from the useHistory hook and use them in both the HOC as 'normal' component?

Answer (score 0):

well as i see you code i dont really find why it not help you, but i use here PrivateRoute file that handle the access to the route.
but why you want to access the useHistory from the HOC

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component,isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props =>
      !isAuthenticated ? (
        <Redirect to='/'/>
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
    />
  );
};
```

implementation

```
`<PrivateRoute exa`ct path="/add" component={AddEmployee} isAuthenticated={isAdmin}/>
```